# MySQL selecting values based on multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like so;

```
foo      bar
1        21
23       17
31       17
23       21
19       9
23       4
31       4
3        27
51       6
31       44
23       44
31       71
```

What I want is to select all the unique values of `bar` that correspond to *both* `23` and `31` in the `foo`column.

i.e. for this table, I'd get the following result;

```
bar
17
4
44
```

`17`, `4`, and `44` all get selected, since for all of those values, two rows exist that correspond to **both** `23` and `31` in the `foo` column.

Even though the values `21` and `71` in `bar` correspond to `23` and `31` in `foo`, they would **not** get selected, since the same value of `bar` isn't present on another row that would correspond to the other number.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Are the combinations of `foo` and `bar` unique? (i.e. `23 -> 17` won't appear twice in the table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    bar
FROM 
    tbl
WHERE
    foo IN (23,31)
GROUP BY
    bar
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

The `2` in `COUNT(*)` represents the amount of values of `foo` you're checking on — in this case, two. If you wanted `bar`s corresponding to all of (23,31,7) for example, change it to `COUNT(*) = 3` because there are three values to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
Select tab1.bar
from
(select bar from table where foo=/*?(say 23)*/) tab1
inner join 
(Select bar from table where foo=/*?(say 31)*/) tab2
on (tab1.bar=tab2.bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT bar
FROM mytable
WHERE foo IN (23,31)
GROUP BY bar
HAVING count(bar) >= 2
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79bcc/13)

Comment: Just FYI, the `>` is unnecessary since there will be at most, two values for `bar` if the combinations are unique.

Comment: @ZaneBien : I have used `>` incase there are cases where count is more than or equal to 2.